# How to Change Database on a Entity Framework Connection

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, .net-4.0, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

I got a ADO.NET Entity Data Model that I want to use on several databases (on the same server), how would you solve it?

```
// This results in a exception, "Specified method is not supported".
private MyEntities _db = new MyEntities();

public IQueryable<MyObject> GetMyObjects(string database)
{
    _db.Connection.ChangeDatabase(database);

    return _db.MyObjects
}

// This works...
private MyEntities _db;
private string entityConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyEntities"].ConnectionString;

public IQueryable<MyObject> GetMyObjects(string database)
{
    _db = new MyEntities(entityConnectionString.Replace("__REPLACE_ME__", database));

    return _db.MyObjects
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd probably modify your "This works..." version, something like this::

```
private MyEntities _db;
private string entityConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyEntities"].ConnectionString;

public IQueryable<MyObject> GetMyObjects(string database)
{
    var ecsb = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder(entityConnectionString);
    var scsb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(ecsb.ProviderConnectionString)
    scsb.InitialCatalog = database;
    ecsb.ProviderConnectionString = scsb.ToString();
    _db = new MyEntities(ecsb.ToString());    
    return _db.MyObjects
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that solution looks much better. Changed the second line in GetMyObjects to "var scsb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(ecsb.ProviderConnectionString);".